# Как избежать Invalid cross-thread access?

Tags: .net, многопоточность, visual-basic

Есть код на Visual Basic:

```
Imports System.Threading

Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits PhoneApplicationPage

    Dim newThread As New Thread(AddressOf ThreadProc)

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ThreadProc()
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To 9
            TextBox1.Text = i
            Thread.Sleep(100)
        Next
        Button1.IsEnabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        newThread.Start()
        Button1.IsEnabled = False
        newThread.Join()
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

При нажатии на кнопку, "`TextBox1.Text = i`" вызывает **`UnauthorizedAccessException`**.

---

Вопрос: как сделать "*`Cross-thread safety action`*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вообще что? Для Silverlight/WPF необходимо использовать `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`, для Windows Forms - TextBox1.Invoke().

[Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx)
[Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)

Comment: Судя по `PhoneApplicationPage` — это Windows Phone приложение, и в нем действительно нужно использовать `Dispatcher`.